# Parse Cloud - Get user informations by objectId

Tags: parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I'm trying to get user lang from **User** class in Parse Cloud. **lang** is one of the columns in **User** class. I wanna get **lang** of the user. My entire Cloud Code is as following (it didn't work):

```
Parse.Cloud.beforeSave('Order', function(request, response) {

    var orderState = request.object.get('orderState');
    var subtitleMessage = '';

    var userLang = '';
    var currentUser = request.object.get('user');
    var userQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
    userQuery.equalTo('objectId', currentUser.id);
    .find()
    .then((result)=>{
        userLang = result.get('lang');
    })

    if (orderState === undefined || ['nonApproved', 'approved', 'delivered', 'canceled'].indexOf(orderState) < 0) {
        response.error("OrderState is null or not one the ['nonApproved', 'approved', 'delivered', 'canceled']!");
    } else {
        var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.Installation);
        query.include('user');
        query.equalTo('user', request.object.get('user'));

        Parse.Push.send(
            {
                where: query,
                data: {
                    title: "MyTitle",
                    alert: subtitleMessage
                }
            },
            {
                success: function() {
                },
                error: function(error) {
                    response.error(error)
                },
                useMasterKey: true
            }
        );
        response.success();
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you provide more details other than "it didn't work"? For example, was there any errors logged or unexpected behaviors? Also, it looks like you're assigning `userLang` in a promise handler and not using it anywhere.

Comment: There was no errors. It gets `undefined` when I logged `userLang`. I want to send push notifications to users according to every user's preferred language. So I want to get `lang` from Parse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer from Jake T. has some good points. Based on his answer and your comment on the question, you could try something like this:

```
Parse.Cloud.beforeSave('Order', function(request, response) {
  var currentUser = request.object.get('user');
  currentUser.fetch({useMasterKey: true}).then(function(user) {
    var userLang = user.get('lang');
    // send push notifications based on userLang here
    response.success();
  }).catch(function(error) {
    // handle any errors here
    console.error(error);
  });
});
```

Comment: I think it should be `user.get('lang')` instead of `result.get('lang')`. Am I right?

Comment: I tried your code, but no success. It returns `null`.

Comment: @PirateofMarmara What is `null`? If `userLang` is `null` that means the user object has `lang` set to `null`.

Comment: `userLang` is `null` and user object has not `lang` set to `null`. Edited user object myself.

Comment: is `user` null? Fetch will return undefined if the user doesn't exist, I believe. so user would be undefined if there isn't actually a user with that object id. Or if `user` on this object isn't actually a User Pointer.

Answer (score 0):

Verify you actually have a User object shell from `request.object.get("user");` And, if you do, you can just call `currentUser.fetch()` instead of performing a query, unless there are other objects you may need to include.

Since you used a query, the result is an array, even if there is only a single object returned (or none, it would be simply `[]`). So, you're doing `Array.get("lang")`, which shouldn't do anything. Try `if( results && results.length > 0 ) user = results[0];`, then you should be able to access `user.get("lang");`

You should have ACL / CLP's set up for your User class. Ideally, these should not be accessible by people who are not the user or master. So, if that is set up properly, your solution may be passing `{useMasterKey:true}` as an option to the query / fetch.

Comment: I'm sure that I'm able to access only user's Id from `request.object.get("user");` Looks like this:  `{"objectId":"XXXXXXXXXX"}`. So I performed new query to access user's `lang` or `username`: `var userQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.User); userQuery.equalTo('objectId', currentUser.id);` There is only a single object returned.